# Cling Library not firing the M Search request regularly

Tags: java, android, android-cling

I am trying to build an Android app, which uses Cling library internally. I am able to get the Application running, however I observed that M-Search packets are not sent each time I invoke the search function as given below.

```
        m_upnpService.getRegistry().removeAllRemoteDevices();
        m_upnpService.getControlPoint().search();
```

It seems like cling library fires the Actual M-search packets only at selected intervals. ( 30 sec approximately in my case).

I want to know why I am not getting M-Search packets into Network every time I call the search function.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sniffer tool I was able to see that above code was working fine ! It was modem which was not forwarding the packets to the device of my interest.
All is well !